# How to use File lock in Spring batch-integration?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

In my spring-batch-integration app, file polling invokes the batchjob for eachfile and this application could be running on multiple servers(nodes) but they all are supposed to read a common directory.Now, I wrote a custom locker which takes the lock on file so that any other instance will not be able to process the same file . code as below

```
public class MyFileLocker extends AbstractFileLockerFilter{

private final ConcurrentMap<File, FileLock> lockCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<File, FileLock>();
private final ConcurrentMap<File, FileChannel> ChannelCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<File, FileChannel>();

@Override
public boolean lock(File fileToLock) {
    FileChannel channel;
    FileLock lock;
    try {
        channel = new RandomAccessFile(fileToLock, "rw").getChannel();
        lock = channel.tryLock();

        if (lock == null || !lock.isValid()) {  
            System.out.println(" Problem in acquiring lock!!" + fileToLock);
            return false;
        }
        lockCache.put(fileToLock, lock);
        ChannelCache.put(fileToLock, channel);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isLockable(File file) {

    return file.canWrite();
}

@Override
public void unlock(File fileToUnlock) {
    FileLock lock = lockCache.get(fileToUnlock);
    try {
    if(lock!=null){
        lock.release();
        ChannelCache.get(fileToUnlock).close();
    }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Now, when i invoke my Spring batch and i try to read that file using flatfileitemreader it gives me

> org.springframework.batch.item.file.NonTransientFlatFileException

which i believe is coming beacuse file is locked. I did some googling and found that NIOLocker locks the file in a way that even the current thread can't read it. I found a [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/compare/master...artembilan:fileLockInCluster) where it shows how to read the locked file but they are using buffer. 
How can I make my file accessible to my FlatfileItemReader.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you really can get access to the locked file content only over `ByteBuffer`:

```
FileChannel fileChannel = channelCache.get(lockedFile);
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate((int) fileChannel.size());
fileChannel.read(byteBuffer);
System.out.println("Read File " + lockedFile.getName() + " with content: " + new String(byteBuffer.array()));
```

Oh! Yeah. You really pointed to my repo :-).

So, with `locker` you don't have choice unless copy/paste the file `byte[]` that way before `FlatfileItemReader` or just inject some custom `BufferedReaderFactory` into the same `FlatfileItemReader`, which converts the locked file to the appropriate `BufferedReader`:

```
new BufferedReader(new CharArrayReader(byteBuffer.asCharBuffer().array()));
```

Comment: In actual prod scenario, files that i am reading can go upto GBs in size and there can be thousands of such file. Do you suggest to create such a large buffers ?

Comment: Yeah... I'm not well with `ByteBuffer`s and can't say how they work internally. Plus I also has been able only find that way to read locked file. Probably people just do the locking some other way and  maybe don't find this `FileChannel` approach as a useful one. You can consider to transfer the data from locked file to the temporary one. And read already the last one line by line in the `FlatfileItemReader`. The `FileChannel.transferTo()` is for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/compare/master...artembilan:fileLockInCluster)  that you shared, looks like you could try the following.

```
//This is from your link (except the size variable)
FileChannel fileChannel = channelCache.get(lockedFile);
int size = (int) fileChannel.size();
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
fileChannel.read(byteBuffer);

//Additional code that you could try
byte[] bArray = new byte[size];

//Write data to the byte array
byteBuffer.get(bArray);

FlatFileItemReader flatFileItemReader = new FlatFileItemReader();
flatFileItemReader.setResource(new ByteArrayResource(bArray));

//Next you can try reading from your flatFileItemReader as usual
...
```

Let me know if it doesn't progress your issue.

Comment: Since you said, your prod implementation could contain files upto multiple GBs, you could read the locked file in a separate thread and keep writing it to a buffer which will be eventually read by `FlatFileItemReader` in a separate thread with the help of `InputStreamResource`

Comment: I have posted an answer for this. Do you see any issues which i must be taking care of ??

Comment: @VarunMaurya , I  am unable to comment there, so writing comment here.  Your solution looks fine to me, but does it solve the problem of huge data? If it is streaming the data for writing into output instead of loading all of it into memory, it is fine. Otherwise some other streaming mechanism should be adopted like BufferedInputStream. Did you get a chance to test it?

Answer (score 0):

Solution : I am creating a temporary file with content of the locked file and processing it. Once processing is done i archive that file and remove the locked and temporary both files. Key here is to create a new file with locked file content. code for below is as follows :

```
File tmpFile = new File(inputFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".lck");     
FileChannel fileChannel = MyFileLocker.getChannelCache().get(new File(inputFile.getAbsolutePath()));
InputStream inputStream = Channels.newInputStream(fileChannel);
ByteStreams.copy(inputStream, Files.newOutputStreamSupplier(tmpFile));
```

Here inputFile is my locked file and tmp file is new file with locked file content. I have also created a method in my locker class to unlock and delete

```
    public void unlockAndDelete(File fileToUnlockandDelete) {
    FileLock lock = lockCache.get(fileToUnlockandDelete);
    String fileName = fileToUnlockandDelete.getName();
    try {
    if(lock!=null){
        lock.release();
        channelCache.get(fileToUnlockandDelete).close();
        //remove from cache
        lockCache.remove(fileToUnlockandDelete);
        channelCache.remove(fileToUnlockandDelete);
        boolean isFiledeleted = fileToUnlockandDelete.delete();
        if(isFiledeleted){
            System.out.println("File deleted successfully" + fileName);
        }else{
            System.out.println("File is not deleted."+fileName);
        }
    }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: @Artem Bilan Do you see any issues here, which i should be worried about.

Comment: M-m-m. Everything looks good. Unless I gave you an advice to copy bytes over the channel of locked file. So, my answer is still acceptable :-). OTOH haven't you tried just rely on the ` Channels.newInputStream(fileChannel);`? Looking into its source code I'd say it is good way to go. It still uses the same `ByteBuffer` but a small one during `InputStream .read()`. So, you are still is fine with the `FlatfileItemReader`, but there is still need the custom `BufferedReaderFactory` to do your logic around locked file!

Comment: Why would i need 'BufferedReaderFactory' ? In my FlatfileItemReader I provide my 'tmpFile ' as resource. Am i missing something here?

Comment: You miss the fact that you can avoid tmp file at all. Thanks to the `Channels.newInputStream(fileChannel);` in the custom `BufferedReaderFactory` we can just stream locked file as normal! Therefore I don't see reason in the tmp file.